# Connections in mxgraph

Tags: bidirectional, edges, mxgraph

I want to know how to avoid bidirectional connections. For example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HR4H.png

Is there any way to do this?

I work with mxGraph, javascript.

**EDIT:** Sorry, maybe I didn’t explain well, I mean if we have two cells (a---> b) cannot be (a <--- b) this may be detected in real time.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `startArrow=classic` from the style of the edge.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn’t explain well, I mean if we have two cells (a---> b) cannot be (a <--- b) this may be detected in real time.

Answer (score 0):

you can check out this example [Validation - Using multiplicities for automatically validating a graph.](http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/validation.html)

> `mxMultiplicity` defines invalid connections along with the error messages that they produce.